# SwiftUI Horizontal Sections Forms

Tags: swift, forms, swiftui

I'm trying to rebuild this in SwiftUI

[image]

So I'm a beginner in SwiftUI and thought I could create a Form with 2 Sections in a HStack which header is "Passengers" with a Stepper another section which header is "Departure" and a DatePicker inside.

My Code is the following:

```
var body: some View {
    Form {
        HStack {
            Section(header: Text("Passengers")) {
                Stepper(value: $passengerCount) {
                    Text("\(self.passengerCount)")
                 }
            }
             Divider()               
             Section(header: Text("Departure")) {
                 //Pseudo date picker
                 Text("21 April, 2020")
             }  
        }
    }
}
```

But the result is like this:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

How can I create 2 Sections like in the first screenshot?

If it is wrong how I'm thinking... how can I do it better?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this? I have the same problem here too

Comment: no sorry, I switched to ReactJS -  I think SwiftUI is not that far. It's probably much easier with UIKit

Answer (score 1):

I juste had the same issue but it is quite easy to find out.
In fact, you have to forget the "Form" as you may know it, i.e. it is here only a visual interface with some useful layout automation.
**Not** a fully functional structure designed to send the information from the user.
Hence the fact that 2 or more forms won't split any of your information.

From there, you create a HStack with 2 "Form" items and voilà :)

```
HStack (spacing: 0) { 

Form {
    your input
    
    }

Form {

    your input
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var body: some View {
        Form {
            HStack {

                VStack {
                    Text("Passengers")
                    Stepper(value: $passengerCount) {
                        Text("\(self.passengerCount)")
                    }
                }
                Divider()
                VStack {

                    Text("Departure")
                    //Pseudo date picker
                    Text("21 April, 2020")

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and if you want a custom stepper like you have you can try even this.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ManualStepperView : View {

    @Binding var value : Int

    var body: some View {

        HStack {

            Text("-")
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .padding(.vertical, 2)
                .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray.opacity(0.2)))
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.value -= 1
            }

            Text("\(value)")
                .padding()

            Text("+")
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .padding(.vertical, 2)
                .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray.opacity(0.2)))
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.value += 1
            }

        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {


    @State var passengerCount : Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            VStack {
                HStack {

                    VStack {
                        Text("Passengers")
                        ManualStepperView(value: $passengerCount)


                    }.frame(width:190)
                    Divider()
                    VStack {
                        Text("Departure")
                        Spacer()
                        //Pseudo date picker
                        Text("21 April, 2020")

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the manual stepper view. But the result of your ContentView aren't 2 separate Sections with Sectionheader: "Passenger" and "Departure". It's just like my second screenshot with your manualStepperView.
I don't want to have passenger stepper and departure DatePicker look like one element. They need to be separated like in the first Screenshot

Answer (score 0):

you can use a GeometryReader and a spacer between the form and the picker, all 3 Hstacked. That will let you have a clear control on the UI porportional distance between the 2 items. Regarding the "section look", overlay each with a roundedRectangle, or using Zstacks. Lastly you could avoid using GR by using spacing in your Hstack (like so, Hstack(spacing: 20)) so you just need to add this to ur code :

```
var body: some View {
Form {
    HStack(spacing: 10) {    // < --- HERE
        Section(header: Text("Passengers")) {
            Stepper(value: $passengerCount) {
                Text("\(self.passengerCount)")
             }
        }
         Divider()               
         Section(header: Text("Departure")) {
             //Pseudo date picker
             Text("21 April, 2020")
         }  
    }
}
```

}